# How do I change values in Rhinoscript in Rhino 3D?

Tags: scripting, 3d, scripting-language

I am using a script in Rhino to import files and and export them to AutoCAD `.dxf`-files.
Before I export I want to change the `Export Scheme` option to `R12 Natural` or `Default`.

I am using the following code line to open the `AcadScheme` dialog window:

```
Rhino.Command "_AcadSchemes ", 0
```

But how do I change the value inside the `Export Scheme` box?

I tried adding things like `"_ExportScheme=Default "` or `"ExportScheme=Default "` but apparently this doesn't work. I know it's probably wrong syntax.

Does anyone know how to alter these values?
I can't gather any useful information from Google or the Rhino Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is in case someone runs into the same issue as I did.
So I contacted one of the developers and I received this answer:

`[...] As I said, you can't access the individual settings via the command line.
 [...] The "Import" function in the DWG/DXF options dialog does not appear to be 
scriptable currently either....
--Mitch`